# Excel and CSV Quotation problems

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, export-to-csv

I have a .csv file that I open in excel.
There is data in it for example:

```
hello there
hi there
bye now
```

I need the data that I edit to have quotations and I do that with a function so it looks like this:

```
"hello there"
"hi there"
"bye now"
```

The problem now comes:
When I save in csv, because that how i need it for my program, and open up the file with a text editor, it shows up like this:

```
"""hello there"""
"""hi there"""
"""bye now"""
```

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: This is normal. A CSV will have quotes for strings that contain commas (ex. the string `Hello, there` is not two fields, so a CSV will write it as `"Hello, there"`, to differentiate those from quotes in strings, the CSV will use `"""`

Comment: So what can I do: 
To when I edit the file and save it as csv and open it with text editor that its only one quotation on each side and not two or more?

Comment: Search and replace?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad all the cells have that. And I have over 3000 cells...

Comment: Any decent text editor will have a global search and replace function -- I don't see the problem here

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks! I didnt know about this replace function. Now I know :)